# Entity Framework Code First with MySql Error

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-5

Below error occurs with Entity Framework Versions 4.3+

http://www.cnblogs.com/shouzheng/archive/2012/03/09/2388177.html

(translated) [Use EntityFramework the Code First Development and one case of MySql database problem](http://translate.google.co.in/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://www.cnblogs.com/shouzheng/archive/2012/03/09/2388177.html&ei=zwelT8CRIoTKrAeuxtX8AQ&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCUQ7gEwAA&prev=/search%3Fq%3DYou%2Bhave%2Ban%2Berror%2Bin%2Byour%2BSQL%2Bsyntax%253B%2Bcheck%2Bthe%2Bmanual%2Bthat%2Bcorresponds%2Bto%2Byour%2BMySQL%2Bserver%2Bversion%2Bfor%2Bthe%2Bright%2Bsyntax%2Bto%2Buse%2Bnear%2B%2527NOT%2BNULL,%2560ProductVersion%2560%2Bmediumtext%2BNOT%2BNULL%29%253BALTER%2BTABLE%2B%2560Migration%2527%2Bat%2Bline%2B5%26hl%3Den%26prmd%3Dimvns)

I want to use latest version of EF as migration feature is not available with version <= 4.1.

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL, 
>     `ProductVersion` mediumtext NOT NULL);
>
> ALTER TABLE `__MigrationH' at line 6    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow,
>   Int32& insertedId)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32
>   statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int32& insertedId)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean
>   force)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(String
>   commandText, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(String
>   sql, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String sql, Object[]
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.BootstrapUsingEFProviderDdl(XDocument
>   model)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<SaveMetadataToDatabase>b__4()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action
>   action)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveMetadataToDatabase()
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext
>   internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext
>   objectContext)    at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Database.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.b_*0(DbContext
>   c)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c*_DisplayClass8.b_*6()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action
>   action)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.b*_4(InternalContext
>   c)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) 
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1
>   action)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action
>   action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
>   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)    at
>   DBPreparationTool.Form1.PrepareDB_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   D:\Workspaces\Experiments\FaizeMBRoot\Source\DBPreparationTool\Form1.cs:line
>   39    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs kevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyMessage(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: Is there any way in which I can overcome this error and move ahead?

Comment: Sorry, (translated) link was wrong. Now it point correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this blog post: http://brice-lambson.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-entity-framework-code-first-with.html